# Visualize question that allows for multiple choices (sum over 100%)

Tags: data-visualization

Example question:

What colors do you like (choose at least 1)?

1. Black
2. White
3. Grey

Example data:

1. Black = 90%
2. White = 50%
3. Grey = 10%

How can I visualize this and demonstrate that some people that chose Black also chose White?

Comment: Have you thought of Venn diagrams (also called Euler's circles)?

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know how many people that chose Black also chose White.

Comment: It can be useful to consider your multiple choice question as a set of multiple binary questions (e.g. "Do you like the color black? Yes/No", etc.). You'll see that possible solutions include multiple bar charts, multiple waffle charts, etc. Here is a quick and dirty example, showing that a part of people who choose "black" necessarily choose "white" too: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6jAE.png. By the way, avoid using checkboxes in surveys, it makes it difficult to distinguish between people who actually mean to answer "no" and non-respondents (even if you force at least to check one option).